# Refresh Android Application after data loading

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android app, i'm inserting initial data using sql script. after insert completed, i need to force stop application or any other thing like that to refresh application to enable database changes.

I called `finish()` at end of insert, but newly inserted data not shown.

how can i do this ?

Comment: Why do you want to finish() your activity?  There are better ways to refresh.

Comment: @Simon what are they ?

Comment: and your data are inserted into ListView?

Comment: How about notifyDatasetChanged?

Comment: @deceiver inserted data shown on `Spinner`

Comment: @TGMCians still i'm unable to try it. i'll update status as soon as possible.

Comment: @Simon i have tried `notifyDatasetChanged`. but it is not working. i have asked a new question about it. see it from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14846752/setnotifyonchangetrue-not-working) .