# setNotifyOnChange(true) not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I have added below codes in `onResume()` method in my android activity.

```
    username.addTextChangedListener(this);
    usernames_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            users.getUserList());
    username.setAdapter(usernames_adapter);
    usernames_adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
```

I'm inserting data into database using sql script. i need to show inserted data on `username` (`username` is a `AutoCompleteTextView)`just after inserting. so i used `usernames_adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);`. but it is not working. i have to `Force Stop` my application to show inserted data on `AutoCompleteTextView`.

How could i solve this ?

Comment: nothing any special things on logcat

Comment: make sure your data list changed & updated; i.e. list of user

Answer (score 1):

Change

> usernames_adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

TO

> usernames_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

this method work only when you delete, update and insert item.